# what is the best shell command for port state?

Tags: command-line

Let's say, i'd like to know whether certain port (e.g. 21) is open or closed.

What is the best shell command for that?

Comment: Are you talking about a port on your machine or a port on another machine?

Comment: on my machine..

Answer (score 3):

My favorites are:

From a local machine

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P 

netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep -v ^unix

netstat -ntulp
```

From a remote box

```
nmap -v -A ip_address
```

Comment: Why bash -c in second command?

Comment: because you often can not pipe output of sudo commands directly.

Comment: Mmh, I don't understand when you cannot. Surely in your example you can (a so you should). Can you show an example when you cannot?

Answer (score 2):

`netstat` will tell you this. To check for all open (listening) ports:

```
netstat -l
```

You can also show all current connections:

```
netstat -an
```

See the manpage for loads more, netstat is a very powerful tool :)

Answer (score 0):

```
nmap -A -T4 localhost -p 80
```

It even shows you OS version and the service on that port

Comment: You should note that nmap isn't part of base and needs installing with apt first

Comment: @Caesium you're right `sudo apt-get install nmap` and also nmap is used in the matrix movie

Answer (score 0):

You can use `telnet` to try to connect to a TCP port on a give host:

```
telnet somehost.example.com 21
```

tries to connect to port 21 on somehost.example.com

If the port is closed you get a message like

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

otherwise you'll see whatever the program listening on that port tells you on connect.